# How do I share an internet connection through USB?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, usb, ethernet

I have two Linux boxes.  One is running KNOPPIX and the other Ubuntu.  I have only one wifi dongle between them, and only one of them has an Ethernet port.  They both have free USB ports however.  I need the box with the dongle to share the connection through a male-to-male USB cable.

I know it is possible to do a similar setup with a desktop and certain portable devices, but I need it between two normal computers.  I cannot buy any additional hardware.

Comment: USB doesn't work that way and can't be used to network 2 computers directly. 

Your best bet is to find an USB/Ethernet adapter, or another Wi-Fi dongle.

Comment: I am already doing this on a window System.Sharing Internet of PC via USB to a my mobile.
now m looking for a way to do the same on my linux box.

Comment: @Gagan Your smartphone can act as both a host and device (USB OTG), your laptop doesn't. It's easier to insert an Ethernet cable in between.

Comment: Now that's USB-C is a thing, this question shines in a new light.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any deeper knowledge, I would suggest looking at the [Linux USB Project](http://www.linux-usb.org/usbnet/), section *USB Host-to-Host Cables*, and possibly [Easy Transfer Cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easy_Transfer_Cable) (although that seems to be mainly a Windows thingy). In any case you are likely to need additional hardware, because the cable probably is not "just wires".

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible, unfortunately. All USB connections must be between a host device (e.g. a computer) and a normal USB device (mouse, etc.). Desktops and laptops are always hosts and therefore cannot connect to each other. Some newer mobile devices implement the USB On-The-Go standard, and can switch between being hosts and normal devices, but this won't be the case for your computers.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Thanks for your time though!

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a USB male-to-male cable, or at least, if some idiot made one it would explicitly violate the USB standard.  The closest thing to it is something like a laplink cable, which is a USB device in the middle that has two male cables coming out of it.  As far as I know, these use proprietary software to communicate with the device and ask it to relay to the other computer.  As such, it won't work as a normal network interface in Linux.

Comment: Well, I have a male-to-male cable.  It came with a cheap digital camera stick thing, which had a full size USB port to connect to the computer.